# In MDriven Enterprise Information, why is there a Processes Hierarchy and also a Processes Tree?

Tags: mdriven

In MDriven Enterprise Information, why is there a Processes Hierarchy and also a Processes Tree? Aren’t they the same thing? Is this not redundant duplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processes are defined by their steps.
A Process step can make use of another processes - ie defining a sub-process.

To both have the complete list of processes and the resulting expanded tree of process and their sub-processes and even their sub-processes (infinity) we added two nodes.

First node is the complete straight list of existing processes regardless if they are sub-processes or not.

Second node is the constructed tree of whom uses who - and a sub-process can then show up multiple times in this tree.[image]

Notice that ApproveNewBulk is re-used in 2 processes in the example below.